# *ngFor get specific numbers index

Tags: angular, ionic4

l have 100 array in data json url . l want to show data arrays only between 7 to 20 . 
l did that but he doesn't work

```
  <tr  *ngFor="let item of weather.hourly_forecast ; let i=index" >

    <td *ngIf="i>20" style="font-weight: bold;">{{item.mslp.metric}}</td>
```

Comment: `*ngIf="i>20"` doesnt say between 7 and 20...

Comment: use weather.hourly_forecast.slice(7,20)

Comment: l did *ngIf="7>20" but he doesn't show anything

Comment: @Eliseo thank you for answer . he is working now

Answer (score 1):

you can use `&&` operator, 
`<td *ngIf="i>7 && i<20" style="font-weight: bold;">{{item.mslp.metric}}</td>`